# Какая последовательность действий для калибровки стерео-камер в OpenCV?

Tags: java, opencv

Моя конечная цель - оставить на изображении только те объекты, которые находятся близко к камере. Я полагаю, что для этого мне нужно составить DepthMap.

Такой пример с этими фотографиями у меня работает: https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d53/tutorial_py_depthmap.html

Я хочу добиться того же самого со своими изображениями. Есть самодельная стерео-камера: две одинаковые бюджетные веб-камеры, которые зафиксированы на штативе.

Я откалибровал камеры, линза не слишком искажает изображение, так что ничего особенного не изменилось, только небольшие черные полоски появились по краям.

Что делать дальше? Только стерео-калибровку (буду очень признателен за примеры на java)? Нужно ли как-то по особенному располагать камеры с линейкой, или достаточно ровно направить их параллельно?

Вот что у меня получилось на данный момент:

[image: левая камера]
[image: правая камера]
[image: итог]